# How to open a link in Chrome from an Electron app?

Tags: javascript, browser, electron

I have an electron app that opens discord links for me, when It was a node CLI application it opened the link in Chrome but now in electron with a UI it opens the link in an electron child window, here is a snippet from the code I am using:

```
var link = 'https://twitter.com/home';
console.log(`opening ${link}`);
open(link)
```

Does anyone know how I would have it open in chrome/ users default browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can use child-process for open links in systems default browser. There is some executables for opening links in systems default browser.
For windows

```
explorer.exe [URL]
```

For MacOS

```
open [URL]
```

For Linux

```
xdg-open [URL]
```